# Slack app and local storage

Tags: slack, slack-api

We are planning a Slack app but we need local storage, we do not want to store any data of user/channel at our server, we want to save it permanently or temporary on local machine of user or in Slack server.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are my thoughts on the topic:

**Local storage solution**

1. You would need to implement a "local" helper-app that every user needs to install. Keep in mind that Slack works on many different platforms. So you would either need to limit your app to certain platforms (e.g browser only), or develop a "helper-app" for all platforms that Slack is currently supporting (e.g. Browser, Windows desktop, Apple desktop, iPhone, Android).
2. You would still need to host your Slack app on a server. Slack requires you to provide a fixed URL to connect to your Slack app, e.g. to invoke a slash command or after pressing a button. Your app would then need to manage the connection with the local helper-app to access the local data storage.

So, I guess it would be technically possible, but would require a lot of effort. And since you will need to host your app on a server anyways, it might be more feasible to also put your user data there.

**Storing data on the Slack server**

It is possible to store user data on the slack server through the user profile. There one can add custom key/value pairs through [`users.profile.get`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.get) and [`users.profile.set`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set)

However, this will not work for slack team related data, like the individual Slack token that is received during the app installation process and needed by the Slack app to use those API methods. So your app needs to at least store the app token centrally together with the slack app itself.