# Is there anyway to add storage to a slack workspace?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775558/slack-app-and-local-storage) from 2018 and was wondering if there is any other way to store data on a slack workspace? I've read through the slack api documentation and still have not found any way to access a slack storage database.

Currently I am using Firebase as my db solution, but preferably I would want to store it to the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

The is no slack storage/database.

The best you can do is upload files on slack.

 https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

But this doesn't seem to solve the purpose you want it for.